# How to get up to 100 products in other language (WPML) from WooCommerce using REST API (python wrapper)

Tags: php, python, wordpress, woocommerce

**Set-up**

My WooCommerce shop has 3 different languages with French as the default language.

I'm using the [Python wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-python).

---

**Code**

`wcapi.get('products/?per_page=100').json()`

gets up to 100 products in the default language (French).

`wcapi.get('products/?lang=en').json()`

gets up to 10 products in the English language.

---

**Question**

How do I combine to two above commands, such that I get up to 100 products in the English language?

[Here WPML shows how to do this in PHP](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/using-wordpress-rest-api-woocommerce-multilingual/#get-products), how can I do this in the Python wrapper?

Comment: What's wrong with `wcapi.get('products/?lang=en&per_page=100')` ?

Comment: FWIW note that an "api" that requires passing a querystring instead of query args (ie `wcapi.get('products', lang='en', per_page=100)` is as badly designed and unpythonic as possible. I suspect it has been written by a wordpress "developper".

Comment: You're probably right, but it gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) pointed out in his commment, it's as simple as,

`wcapi.get('products/?lang=en&per_page=100')`